# Adding a constraint to a simple Optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

I've looked at several questions like this on SO and still cannot resolve it. But I'm looking to add a constraint where the change in volume (New Volume / Old Volume - 1 >= -10%) cannot be less than -10%.

**Example**

| Customer | Old_volume | Elasticity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 100 | -0.68 | 15.00 |

```
#example dataset
df <- data.frame(customer = c("X"),
                 old_volume = c(100),
                 elasticity = c(-0.68),
                 price = c(15.00))

#function
f3 <- function(x) {
         new_vol = 100 * (1+(-0.68 * x))
         new_rev = new_vol * (15.00 * (1+x))
         new_cost = new_vol * 11.25
     
         return(new_rev - new_cost)  }

n_vol <- function(x) {
         new_vol = 100 * (1+(-0.68 * x))
         return(new_vol)  }

#example run function
f3(0.25)
>>>[1] 622.5

#running the optimization
res <- optimize(f3, lower=0, upper=10, maximum = TRUE)
res$maximum
>>>0.6102941

res$objective
>>>[1] 754.9081

n_vol(0.6102941)
>>> 58.5
```

Therefore vol change % = 58.5/100-1 = -0.415, however I want to limit this to -0.1.

Now I want to add in a constraint where ***new_vol/old_vol-1 >= -0.1***. However, I'm not sure how to add this in using `Optimize()`, `optim()` or `lpsolve()`. I was reading through the `lpsolve()` documentation and it seemed like the way to go, but I am confused as to what my vector of coefficients would be in the *objective.in*. Also looking at other packages like *constrOptim*, it seemed too complex for something one dimensional.

Thanks

As an example, normally on Excel, I would have a bunch of columns with these calculations and run solver with the constraint of volume change >= -0.1. However running a macro takes too long with rows > 1,000

EDIT: Added input example

Comment: thanks @G.Grothendieck. Added an input example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate your new boundary algebraically.

```
change_inv <- function(frac, oldvol = 100) {  oldvol * (1 + frac) }
n_vol_inv <- function(vol) { (vol / 100 - 1) / -0.68 }
n_vol_inv(vol = change_inv(frac = -0.1))
# [1] 0.1470588
max_x <- optimize(f3, 
    lower = 0, 
    upper = n_vol_inv(vol = change_inv(-0.1)), 
    maximum = TRUE)
max_x
# $maximum
# [1] 0.1469922
# 
# $objective
# [1] 535.9664
n_vol(max_x$maximum) / 100 - 1
# [1] -0.09995469
```

Unfortunately, this means that the maximum is just the boundary.

Comment: I would have though the constraint "volume change >= -0.1" would set a lower bound.

Comment: thank you this worked wonderfully! This may require a whole new question, but what would happen if I were to have 2 different constraints? i.e. New_rev change > 0%?

I'm assuming I would need to use a different function/library to solve this as it has become more complex correct?